# WebRequest Getting "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel" error on some websites. (Not on all websites)

Tags: vb.net

I developed a self hosted webservice (vb.net) which is downloading some website sources from internet.

when i try to download getting "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel" on some websites. (%95 percentage is working without error)

I added below codes into webservice but nothing changed

```
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = Function() True
    ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = True
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
```

Why i'm getting this error message, anybody has an idea?

Comment: If you're in Windows 10, `SecurityProtocol` is already `TLS12`. If you're in Windows 7, you need to set `SecurityProtocolType.Tls12` explicitly, so, in some cases, you also need a `ServerCertificateValidationCallback`. This one: `ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = True` you really don't want it. But it doesn't cause this specific issue. Always set a `User Agent` header, but do not use a recent Browser header, use the Internet Explorer 11 header or a not-so-recent version of FireFox etc. (there's a reason). Some Sites (still) don't use Tls12, so maybe also add Tls11.

Comment: Note that Windows 10 has TLS13 available and .Net Framework 4.8 has the `SecurityProtocolType.Tls13` value. But all sites that already use TLS13 also support TLS12.

Comment: @Jimi thanks for reply. but i have tried all of things that you said. but nothing changed. Same webservice working good on another computer.

Comment: You understand that, with the information provided, I can only provide some generic suggestions. You should, at least, share the address of one of the problematic Sites (so it can be tested) and define your current context: Operating System types and versions where you tested your code, type of Solution (Console, WPF, UWP, WinForms etc.), type and version of the .Net Framework (.Net FW, Core 2, Core 3, Core 3.1 etc.), the actual code used (you just posted a couple of not so meaningful lines). Then, hardware and/or software proxies etc.

Comment: @Jimi Yes you're right.  I want to collect data from this website : https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/ - Webservice is selfhosted (Winform). Just defined new webclient and tried wc.downloadstring("https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/"), I think that my computer has a problem with this, because same code working on Windows Server 2016. My computer has Windows 2008 Server R2

Comment: @Jimi .NEt Framework 4.6.1

Comment: Your Operating System may not have a required a cipher suite (`TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256`, probably, so it's *unsafe*). The same applies to Windows7. WebBrowsers install their own cipher suites, independent from the OS availability.

Comment: @Jimi thanks for answer. I will search another website for coronavirus statistics